# how do i add my API response in the form of json into a variable in java?

Tags: java, json, api

```java
package com.wallet.credit.service;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.wallet.credit.entities.Credit;

public class CrDbTrans {
    
    public void trans() {
        int cramnt = 0, dbamnt = 0;
        
        CrDbTrans httpclient = new CrDbTrans();
        
        String json_string = Credit.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject temp1 = new JSONObject(json_string);
        
        if(cramnt < dbamnt) {
            
        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse it to an Entity object you can  use The Jackson ObjectMapper class:
Credit credit= new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Credit.class);